# Master Slave Feature in Apache Geode

Tags: high-availability, master-slave, geode

Apache Geode has the feature of clustering using multi-site WAN but is there any other configuration changes So we can you use HA feature or master - slave feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure WAN replication to only happen in one direction - from a primary (or master) to a secondary site. You would do this by only creating a gateway-sender in your primary site.

However it's usually best to configure Geode to use active-active WAN replication where both sites are replicating to each other. That way if you fail over to your secondary site it can queue up events to replicate to your primary site when it comes back online.

A common pattern would be to configure geode to use active-active WAN in two different sites, but then designate a primary site for your entire application stack (webservers, geode, other services, etc.).